# Best Practice to open a port in private subnet for an Application used by Another application in same Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just wanted to know the 
Best Practice to open a port in private subnet in AWS for an Application used by another application in same Private Subnet.

Currently i have opened the port for the same subnet in Security Rules.

Just wanted to confirm is there any better way for this?

Comment: Security Groups is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I like to put separate applications in separate security groups and in the rules reference the security rather than an IP range. For example:

```
AppA => Sg-A
AppB => Sg-B
Sg-A rules allow access on port N from Sg-B
```

Now any instance in Sg-B can access AppA on port N.